# Laravel 4, Mysql Error 1054 column not found

Tags: php, mysql

i have table structure like this
[image]

but when i try to create new person laravel throw the following error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pob' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `people` (`name`, `pob`, `dob`, `title`, `position`, `institution_id`, `photo`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (My Name is Dre, Ciamis, 1987-08-16, , , 2, , 2014-11-05 02:26:17, 2014-11-05 02:26:17))
```

i got the same error when i try to execute the SQL from phpmyadmin.

please guide me to fix this.

Comment: There should be quotes around your *string* values `(My Name is Dre, Ciamis, 1987-08-16, , , 2, , 2014-11-05 02:26:17, 2014-11-05 02:26:17)` since they are for the most part, strings `('My Name is Dre', 'Ciamis', '1987-08-16', , , 2, , '2014-11-05 02:26:17', '2014-11-05 02:26:17')` yet I don't know why there are extra commas, so check that and show us your actual query code.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 : yep, i am sure table_name and column_name is matches.
Fred-ii- : of course, in phpmyadmin i add quotes for each values. still, it's throw error

Comment: You will need to show us your query "source" code then. There's not much we can do without it.